# Web service with Entity framework connection

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework

I have created a web site in C# 2010 with Entity framework, in the same i have also added one web service and deployed the same on server.

Now my web site is working good ,but when i open web service the asmx page will open up but the method which require database connection is not working.

I have used project dll in my web service for connection.

Now every time when i run web service method which connect to database it show me the message PAGE NOT FOUND.

Please suggest

Exception details:

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

The web.config file needs the connection string for the Model, plus some bits and pieces. Make sure that it contains the following, and change the connection string to have your own server, database, and authentication details:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="YourModelNameHere" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RCMarketModel.csdl|res://*/YourModelNameHere.ssdl|res://*/YourModelNameHere.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=Your Server Name;Database=Your Database Name;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

These are probably best copied from yout web site web.config file, rather than from the above, but you need the three sections:

`<ConfigSections>`, `<connectionStrings>`, and `<entityFramework>`

Comment: Problem remain the same i had alter the web config of Dataentity with the above detail. But its show error "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Comment: OK. A bit more detail. Are the web site and Web Service on the same server? Are you using the same user for both?

Comment: yes,now i tell you that i have created a dot net project with entity framwork then i have added one more project for web service. the web service use the same entity connection what web project is using. but at the time of dubigigng the web service it gives me error "entity exception was unhandled by user code the underlying provider failed on open"                      but the same thing is working if i give direct connection without entity connection to my web service.